Animate a mesh "shell" morphing around another mesh/object
I'm following this tutorial from Ducky 3D where he morphs one Icosphere around another using some Geometry Nodes magic. I am trying to adapt the method to a non-spherical shape (a cube, to test) and want to morph the outside mesh around the inner object in a random but fluid way.
How can I get this outer shell to morph around the cube in the center in a smooth animated way that adheres to the cube's shape?
Using the seed of the random number in the geo-nodes doesn't work because it hitches from one value to the next, and I don't know how to interpolate the seed so it transitions smoothly.


EDIT: I missed the one Translate Geometry node that he throws in at the end of that chain pictured above. This deforms the shell around the cube almost in the way I'm looking for. I want to get it to work without any clipping, though (you can see some in the image in the question in the upper left of the cube)



Tut is just a sphere rotated arround another sphere ... in your case you would need something like a sphere shrinkwrapped (modifier od geo-nodes) on cube ... I guess.
